# how can i add custom theme support in only an area?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-areas, viewengine

i am very new to asp.net mvc and trying to build a small CMS with theme support.

while i was researching the subject on the net, i've found some examples but none of them helped me exactly.
[here is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9zB0.png).

i have 2 Areas. it was working nicely before i moved view folders into Default theme folder.

i want to add "theme folder" support in my ONLY "Front" Area.

i am using .net framework 4.5.2.